# How can I show edit text box dynamically

Tags: android

I have a layout where edit text box are there,How can I show it dynamically.means if my database having number of rows 10 then 10 edit text box will be come if it 5 then five will come.like this.how can i show it please help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In this is the case, I believe that best way to do this is to use a ListView and then populate it via a CursorAdapter. The layout of each item will be an EditText which you will inflate in the newView() and then set any value you want from your Cursor.

For an example, you can check here: http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/11/custom-cursoradapters/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You really ought to use a Listview, but incase that's not the point...Here's the solution.

Have a `LinearLayout` with a vertical orientation.

```
LinearLayout ll_table = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll_table);
ll_table.addView( <Put Inflated View Here> );
```

Now the inflated View can be simple as a EditText or a Compilcated layout...

For a Simple EditText

```
EditText edt = new EditText(mContext);
edt.setText("whatever");
ll_table.addView(edt);
```

for a complex layout

```
View view = View.inflate(mContext,R.layout.complex_layout,null);
ll_table.addView(view);
```

Do consider using a `ListView` though.

Answer (score 0):

make one linearlayout
Like 
Use This Code and Check

```
 LinearLayout l1 = new LinearLayout(this);
            l1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                EditText e1 = new EditText(this);
                e1.setTag(i);
                l1.addView(e1);

            }

            setContentView(l1);
    }

    setContentView(l1);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to take a linear layout in xml file and according to the records with using for loop u can create edittext field dynamically.

```
for (int i=0;i<records;i++)
{

EditText et= new EditText(this);

linearLyaou.addView(et);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?= $_post['name'] ?>"/>
<input type="text" name="lastname" value="<?= $_post['lastname'] ?>"/>
.......
....
....
....
etc
```

Comment: This is a question for Android, not PHP.